How to Manually Upgrade an Outdated Linux 3.10.65 ARMv7l Kernel on an Industrial Computer
I have Linux 3.10.65 armv7l kernel on my industrial computer, need to upgrade it manually is it possible if it is, how?

CPU Quad-core ARM Cortex-A7 Processor

Linux 3.10.65

FLASH 8GB EMMC

RAM 1GB DDR3


I am a Linux user already but the kernel is too old than i used before, I do not know kernel3.10 well and the Linux 3.10 kernel series reached end of life and it will no longer receive maintenance updates that patch critical security vulnerabilities. So I need to upgrade it.

I'm 99.9% sure your device is not running a standard Linux kernel but instead it's something heavily patched by your OEM. ARM is a very standards averse platform and it's quite rare for the mainline kernel to work on an ARM device out of the box.
If your OEM has published the source code, you can diff it against the mainline kernel and see what patches were applied and then try to apply them on top of a new kernel release but considering how fast the Linux kernel is being developed, using such patches even on a kernel which is a few releases newer becomes a literal nightmare and unless you're a seasoned kernel hacker, there's very little chance you'll be able to fix the patches to make them apply.
TLDR: your only option is to run the vendor supplied kernel or get a newer device.

Here is the product link, I totally understand your comment thanks a lot.

The product page is here but the OEM seemingly provides nothing https://www.dwin-global.com/8-0-inch-1024768-capacitive-linux-display-dmt10768t080_35wtcindustrial-grade-product/ TBO it's illegal not to provide kernel sources because Linux is GPL2. They are basically violating the license. If they have their business in your Western country, you may try to sue them. I'm not joking. They have kernel updates but not for all products: https://www.dwin-global.com/kernel-upgrade/

So I just wonder is it possible to add python, pip, git etc. to this system because I cannot use this commands in this kernel I mean kernel cannot have this features.

Please ask a new question.
